# SQL syntax issue related to totalcount in combination with dates

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can any body help me with the following SQL statement?

What am I doing wrong here?
It is giving me no result however there should be some...

The desired result should be a list or errorsdetails with the total number of times it is in the database (mdb) based on the selected date-period.

PS sorry for my badly written English..
Many thanks 
Koen

```
sSQL = "SELECT ErrorDetail, count(*) AS totalcount FROM tblErrors WHERE DisplayName = " & cbox_modules.Text & " AND ErrorDate BETWEEN #" & startdate & "# AND #" & enddate & "# GROUP BY ErrorDetail"
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have delimiters around a string.  Also, you should be using parameterized queries instead of glomming strings together.

Comment: Please study this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thanks a lot Xm7X for the tip, it was missing the single quotes for displayname..

Comment: Suppose to have a DisplayName like `O'Hara`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "DisplayName" column is a string, ensure you surround it with apostrophes:

```
SELECT 
  ErrorDetail, 
  COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
FROM tblErrors 
WHERE DisplayName = '" & cbox_modules.Text & "' AND ErrorDate BETWEEN #" & startdate & "# AND #" & enddate & "#  
GROUP BY ErrorDetail
```